# c# calculator minus not working properly

Tags: c#

I've got to make a calculator for school, everything works except the minus button: 5-5 = -5 for example.
I know that the problem exists somewhere in my case "minus" but I just
can't get it figured out..
Here's the code.
Most of the variables are in dutch, I hope that won't be a problem!

Note: this problem exists when i do this: 5 - 5, so not using the equals button.

```
    private int totaal = 0;
    private Boolean lastClicked, equalsPressed, tussen = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(((Button)sender).Name){
            case "one":
                if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "1";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "1";
                }
            break;

            case "two":
            if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "2";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "2";
                }
            break;

            case "three":
            if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "3";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "3";
                }
            break;

            case "four":
            if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "4";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "4";
                }
            break;

            case "five":
            if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "5";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "5";
                }
            break;

            case "six":
            if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "6";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "6";
                }
            break;

            case "seven":
            if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "7";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "7";
                }
            break;

            case "eight":
            if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "8";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "8";
                }
            break;

            case "nine":
            if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "9";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "9";
                }
            break;

            case "zero":
            if (tussen)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = "";
                    tussen = false;
                }

                if (equalsPressed)
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "0";
                    equalsPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uitkomstBox.Text = uitkomstBox.Text + "0";
                }
            break;

            case "plus":
            totaal = totaal + Convert.ToInt32(uitkomstBox.Text);
            uitkomstBox.Text = totaal.ToString();
            tussen = true;
            lastClicked = true;
            break;

            case "minus":
            totaal = totaal - Convert.ToInt32(uitkomstBox.Text);
            uitkomstBox.Text = totaal.ToString();
            tussen = true;
            lastClicked = false;
            break;

            case "clear":
            uitkomstBox.Text = "";
            totaal = 0;
            break;

            case "equals":
            if (lastClicked)
            {
                uitkomstBox.Text = (totaal + Convert.ToInt32(uitkomstBox.Text)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                uitkomstBox.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(uitkomstBox.Text) - totaal).ToString();
            }
            equalsPressed = true;
            totaal = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the logic of the plus and minus buttons you need to check.

Take yourself through the code step by step.

In the beginning, `totaal` = 0 and `uitkomnstBox.Text` is empty. Then you click "5". So `uitkomstBox.Text` is "5". Then you click the "minus" button. `totaal` now changes to -5. i.e. before you have even entered a number to subtract from it. Then you click "5" again (to complete 5 - 5) but `totaal` doesn't change in this case until you click the equals button, at which point it hits that `lastClicked` logic which I don't really get... (I think it should end up as zero after that but you said the problem exists if you don't click "equals").

So it's not just that you're subtracting twice but you're subtracting before you even have a number to subtract.

As a possible solution, what I'd suggest is something like this: execute the logic of the operation ("plus" or "minus") after the next number is complete.

i.e. When someone clicks "minus" save this in memory somewhere until they have finished entering the next number, then subtract it from the total, or if they clicked "plus" add it. For the first number, process  "plus" (e.g. 5 - 5 is processed as if it was entered as + 5 - 5)

```
private char operation = '+'; // Default first operation to "plus"

// Your other code... 
// ...
// ...

case "plus" :
   if (operation == '+') {
      totaal += Convert.ToInt32(uitkomnstBox.Text);
   }
   if (operation == '-') {
      totaal -= Convert.ToInt32(uitkomnstBox.Text);
   }
   operation = '+';
   // anything else you want
   break;

case "minus" :
   if (operation == '+') {
      totaal += Convert.ToInt32(uitkomnstBox.Text);
   }
   if (operation == '-') {
      totaal -= Convert.ToInt32(uitkomnstBox.Text);
   }
   operation = '-';
   // anything else you want
   break;

case "equals" :
   if (operation == '+') {
      totaal += Convert.ToInt32(uitkomnstBox.Text);
   }
   if (operation == '-') {
      totaal -= Convert.ToInt32(uitkomnstBox.Text);
   }
   operation = '+';   // Set back to default for next calculation

   // anything else you want
   break;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are subtracting the number twice. Once in the `switch` statement and then again here:

```
if (lastClicked)
{
    uitkomstBox.Text = (totaal + Convert.ToInt32(uitkomstBox.Text)).ToString();
}
else
{
    // You have already subtracted the number but then you are subtracting it again!
    uitkomstBox.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(uitkomstBox.Text) - totaal).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Noted, I changed my equals code, but the problem still exists if i do: 5-5-5, so not touching the equals button.

Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are subtracting from `totaal` twice. Are you sure that adding works correctly? Check the code for your "=" button.

Answer (score 0):

Also, maybe consider storing numbers for calculation in some counter int (or any other number type, if you are planning to allow fractions), rather than in textbox, since then you have to convert it back and forth just for the calculation.